# Item selected from dropdown-item not opening on first click?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

There is a dropdown menu like this.

```
function changeRange(range) {
    var options = {
        data.......
    };
    var options1 = {
        data.......
    };
    var options2 = {
        data.......
    };
    if (range === 'last30') {
        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#revenue"),
            options
        );
    } else if (range === 'month') {
        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#revenue"),
            options1
        );
    } else if (range === 'partner30') {
        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#revenue"),
            options2
        );
    } else if (range === 'partnermonth') {
        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#revenue"),
            options3
        );
    }

    chart.render();
}

<div class="widget widget-chart-one">
    <div class="widget-heading">
        <h5 class="">Total Coins</h5>
        <div class="task-action">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="pendingTask" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-horizontal">
                        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                        <circle cx="19" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                        <circle cx="5" cy="12" r="1"></circle>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="pendingTask" style="will-change: transform;">
                    <button class="dropdown-item" onclick="changeRange('last30')" value="last30">Mobile 30 Day</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" onclick="changeRange('month')" value="month">Mobile Monthly</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" onclick="changeRange('partner30')" value="partner30">Partner 30 Day</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" onclick="changeRange('partnermonth')" value="partnermonth">Partner Monthly</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
        <div id="revenue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: When I choose an option from the Dropdown menu, it does not load on the first click. For example, I have the "Mobile 30 days" graphic on my page, and I want to switch to the "Mobile Monthly" option. When I click on the "Mobile Monthly" option, the page refreshes, but the graphic does not change. When I click the same again, the graphic I want opens this time. I even explain the photo I put below. It tries and fails to open a chart below the previous chart on the first click, updates the chart on the second click. I think conditional statements cause the problem. What do you think?

At the first click, it tries to open the graphic I want here. Then, for 1 or 2 seconds, it comes and goes. On the second click, it now replaces the top graphic with what I want.

[image]

Also, I get the following error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
[image]

Comment: If you click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor, you can make a [mcve] to show what is going on. You will need a little bit of example data too plus the [cdn version of apexcharts](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/apexcharts)

Comment: Actually, I'm guessing something, but I couldn't figure it out. var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#revenue"),
            options
        ); In this part, it feels like I'm constantly creating a new chart under all circumstances, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You creatin new chart every time function executes, instead try updating it. You can do it without referencing the instance of the chart with `exec`. https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#exec

```
ApexCharts.exec('mychart', 'updateOptions', options);
```

But first you need to add id to your options

```
chart:{
  id: 'mychart',
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do I have to write this statement in every condition? My question is where do I create the first graph?

Comment: If you getting data from api, render chart after that, if you using for example mvc, anywhere inside `<script>` tag and yes update in every condition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244383/discussion-on-answer-by-patryk-laszuk-item-selected-from-dropdown-item-not-openi).